# Javascript function not working properly in IE<10

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have this link, that simply hides itself and shows the `fb:comments` element

```
<a onclick="comments(this)"> + Comments (
    <fb:comments-count href="http://some.url.com" fb-xfbml-state="rendered">
        <span class="fb_comments_count">1</span>
    </fb:comments-count>
)
</a>

<div class=\"facebook-comments\"><!-- default style for this is 'display:none'-->
    <fb:comments href=\"http://some.url.com" width="644" num_posts="10">
    </fb:comments>
</div>
```

this is the `comments()` function:

```
function comments(src){
    //hide the 'a' element that called this function
    src.style.display="none"; 

    //show comments element 
    src.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('facebook-comments')[0].style.display="block";
    return false;
}
```

This works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari and IE10 too, but it's buggy in IE<10, it happens that when i click the `+ Comments (#)` link it disappears but the comments div is not appearing, so the link becomes useless.

Is it an IE problem or did I do something wrong?

In both cases, how can I solve it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @JanDvorak ok, so how can i do the same thing on IE?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` is available since IE8 (or just use jQuery)

Comment: @JanDvorak make an answer with this so that i can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) is not supported by old IE. MDN claims support since IE9.

Another option is [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector) or [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll). Supported since IE8:

```
src.parentNode.querySelector('.facebook-comments').style.display="block";

//OR

src.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.facebook-comments')[0].style.display="block";
```

If you want to support IE7 as well (or if you like its syntax), your best bet is to use a framework or library. The most popular framework available is [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (The [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) engine, which is a part of it, is available for a separate download as well). With jQuery:

```
$(src).parent().find(".facebook-comments:first").show();
```

If you want to avoid external libraries *and* you want to support IE7, your choices are quite limited, but [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) is still available (since IE 5.5). Sadly, [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList) isn't:

```
var elems = src.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div")
for(var i = 0; i<elems.length; i++){
  elem = elems[i];
  if(elem.className.matches(/(^| )facebook-comments( |$)/){
    elem.style.display = "block";
    break;
  }
}
```